# Como efetuar uma pesquisa de texto e a tag Select juntos?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Estou aqui pois estou com dificuldades de efetuar uma pesquisa como qualquer outra com `<input text>` e botão "pesquisar" só que com a tag `<select>` onde contem em cada `<option>` a `value` respectiva da pesquisa. A questão é no jQuery pois no php estou me virando aqui, sistema modelo MVC, espero poder com esta questão ajudar outros membros.

Aqui esta o html:

```
<div class='fba_campo'>
    <input type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa_faq" placeholder="<?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Pesquisar")?>" class='faq_wh_100'>
</div>


<select name='' id='faq_options' class='faq_wh_100'>
    <option value='0'><?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Todos")?></option>
    <option value='Guia'><?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Guia")?></option>
    <option value='Materiais'><?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Materiais")?></option>
    <option value='Produtos'><?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Produtos")?></option>
    <option value='Vídeos'><?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Vídeos")?></option>
</select>

<div class='fba_button'>
    <input type="button" id="faq_bt_pesquisar" value='<?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Pesquisar")?>' class='faq_wh_100'>
</div>
```

E a `div` que receberá os valores da pesquisa é esta que esta em `.hide()`:

```
<div id="tabela_pesquisa">
    <center>
        <h2 id="h2_transicao_faq" style="color:black;"></h2>    
        <center><img src="<?=$url?>control/img/inwhats/loading_big.gif" id="loading_big_faqpesquisa" style="display: none;"></center>
    </center>

    <table class="tabela_faq">

    </table>

</div>
```

E aqui está o javascript:

```
$('body').on("click","#faq_bt_pesquisar",function(){

    $("#h2_transicao_faq").html("<?=$i->getMensagemIdioma("Pesquisando...")?>");
    $("#faq_area_conteudo").hide();
    $("#tabela_pesquisa").show();
    $("#loading_big_faqpesquisa").css("display","block");

    setTimeout(function(){

        $.post("<?=$url?>insoft/header/ajaxCarregapesquisafaq",$("#form_pesquisa").serialize(),function(data){


            var resposta = eval(data);
            if(resposta.length > 0){

                alert(data)
                $("#loading_big_faqpesquisa").css("display","none");
                $("#h2_transicao_faq").html("");
                var html = "";
                for(var b = 0;b < resposta.length;b++){
                     html += "<tr>";
                     html += "<td>"+resposta[b]['pergunta']+"</td>";
                     html += "</tr>";
                 }


            }else{

            }

        });

    }, 2000);

});
```

Aqui está o controlador no php:

```
public function ajaxCarregapesquisafaq(){

    $filtro   = $_POST['filtro'];

    if(isset($_POST['pesquisa'])){

        if($filtro == "Guia" || $filtro == "0"){
            $obj_cat    = new daoCategoria();
            $cat        = $obj_cat->Where(" ica_nome LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' OR ica_codigo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' ")->Consultar();
            $categorias = array();
            foreach($cat as $ct){
                $categorias = array("categoria"=>utf8_encode($ct['ica_nome']),"codigocat"=>$ct['ica_codigo']);
            }

            echo json_encode($categoria);


        }elseif($filtro == "Materiais"){
            $obj_mat   = new daoMaterial();
            $mat       = $obj_mat->Where(" ima_titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' OR ima_codigo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' ")->Consultar();
            $materiais = array();
            foreach($mat as $mt){
                $materiais[] = array("material"=>utf8_encode($mt['ima_titulo']),"codigomat"=>$mt['ima_codigo']);
            }

            echo json_encode($material);

        }elseif($filtro == "Produtos"){
            $obj_pro  = new daoProduto();
            $pro      = $obj_pro->Where(" ipd_descricao LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' OR ipd_codigo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' ")->Consultar();
            $produtos = array();
            foreach($pro as $pd){
                $produtos[] = array("produto"=>utf8_encode($pd['ipd_descricao']),"codigopd"=>$pd['ipd_codigo']);
            }

            echo json_encode($produtos);

        }elseif($filtro == "Videos"){
            $obj_vid = new daoVideo();
            $vid     = $obj_vid->Where(" ive_titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' OR ive_codigo LIKE '%".$_POST['pesquisa']."%' ")->Consultar();
            $videos  = array();
            foreach($vid as $vd){
                $videos[] = array("video"=>utf8_encode($vd['ive_titulo']),"codigovid"=>$vd['ive_codigo']);
            }

            echo json_encode($videos);
        }

    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("resultado"=>"erro"));
    }

}
```

Agradeço muito, desculpe o javascript estar incompleto pois ainda estou verificando mas gostaria que me ajudassem com opiniões também, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado de novo!

Comment: Eu não entendi exatamente o que você está precisando fazer. Quando o botão for clicado, qual valor você precisa enviar para o PHP?

Comment: Quando clicado em pesquisar o texto a ser pesquisado tem que ser respectivo ao valor da tag select para buscar na tabela respectiva, entendeu? obrigado pelo tempo :)

Comment: @MauroAlexandre obrigado , agora to precisando fazer a pesquisa no banco de dados respectivo relacionado a option selecionada, pois cada option tem o nome de uma tabela que contem dados a serem pesquisados, novamente obrigado pelo seu tempo para me ajudar.

Comment: @LucasPereira porque tens esta linha `$("#form_pesquisa").serialize()`? não vejo em lado nenhum essa `form`? é a+i que queres ter o valor do select certo? nesse caso devias ter aí `$('#faq_options').val()`

Comment: @Sergio a tag form esta mas não inclui na questão, desculpe

Comment: <form method="post" id="form_pesquisa" autocomplete="off">

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda de vocês, me ajudaram bastante, consegui achar um meiod e fazer e logo postarei aqui a resolução ok abraços obrigado novamente pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria algo assim...

```
$("body").on("click","#faq_bt_pesquisar",function(){
  $("#h2_transicao").html("<?=$i->getMensagemIdioma("Pesquisando...")?>");
  $("#loading").css("display","block");
  $("#faq_area_conteudo").hide(); /*div com o conteudo anterior a ser escondido*/

  var dados = { textoPesquisa : $('pesquisa_faq').val(), optionsPesquisa : $('faq_options').val()};

  $.post( "<?=$url?>insoft/faq/ajaxcarregaconteudo", dados)
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Dados recebidos: " + data );
  });
});
```

Criei um objeto JSON 'dados' que vai levar os dados do campo.

Você também poderia encapsular os campos num form com id="formPesquisa" e ao invés de setar o 'dados' na mão poderia fazer assim...

```
var dados = $('#formPesquisa').serialize();
```

*(detalhe que neste caso os campos teriam que ter o "name" setado)